# Drupal: Updating a module broke the site

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

After I tried to update a module in drupal, through the admin panel, it broke down & displays Site encountered an unexpected error. The site was almost 3 years old and is on I believe version 8 something. The verbose of the error is:

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "paragraph" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (line 150 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php).
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getHandler('paragraph', 'views_data') (Line: 177)
views_views_data()
call_user_func_array('views_views_data', Array) (Line: 392)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invoke('views', 'views_data') (Line: 245)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->getData() (Line: 162)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->get('node_field_data') (Line: 85)
Drupal\views\Plugin\ViewsHandlerManager->getHandler(Array, NULL) (Line: 889)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->getHandlers('sort') (Line: 1040)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->_initHandler('sort', Array) (Line: 898)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->initHandlers() (Line: 2303)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->preExecute() (Line: 1692)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->preExecute(Array) (Line: 1627)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->executeDisplay('page_1', Array) (Line: 77)
Drupal\views\Element\View::preRenderViewElement(Array)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 100)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. Support for this callback implementation is deprecated in 8.8.0 and will be removed in Drupal 9.0.0. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725', 'silenced_deprecation', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 781)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 372)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 227)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 156)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 191)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 128)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 82)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 694)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

any idea how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

1. delete all the configuration related to paragraph module from database tables and clear cache.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).